# Where are the global variables of the dynamic library file loaded to?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, loader

Ideally, each shared library is loaded to the physical memory only once to save memory. But are the data section and bss section in the so file merged into those of the executable file at compilation time? Or the whole frame containing the data section and bss section is subject to copy-on-write every time a user program changes the value?

Comment: I mean libraries shared by most user programs like libc.

Comment: Note that the BSS segment doesn't contain any data, since it's for all the stuff that's zero-initialzied during static initialization (e.g. everything that's later dynamically initialized). So in some sense, yes, those pages will probably start out as COW-copies of some canonical all-zero page. (This is a nice question.)

Comment: Pure speculation, but I have suspicion that this just boils down to how `mmap` works and isn't really related to C and GCC at all. The loader typically mmaps the DSO file, so if the kernel uses COW for mmap, then it's reasonable that the data segment also starts out as a COW copy.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I want to make my question clearer: I assume the global variables are not that many, so COW on 4KB frame for each so file is a waste. So I think they should be merged into the executable. Am I right?

Comment: The COW overhead wouldn't be 'every time a user program changes the data', but would only be 'the first time a (new) process changes the data'.  At worst.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "merged into the executable". The program text itself is memory-mapped, too, and presumably also subject to mmap's COW policies. But note that the text segment can and should usually be non-writable, and the data segment must be, so giving up on a separate data segment would require making the text segment('s mapping) writable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for your clarification, that's what I supposed to mean. But the answer is?

Comment: Just for another clarification: what I want to know is: is a separate data/bss section loaded, when a new so library (has global variables) is loaded, or the global variables used in the so library is already assigned memory at the data/bss section when loading the excutable?

Answer (score 0):

The answer do this is no different when the globals lie in a shared library vs the main program; both are shared in exactly the same way. They are a writable `MAP_PRIVATE` map of the program image on disk (or of `MAP_ANON` pages for bss), which are generally implemented as copy-on-write (COW) references to the corresponding page of the file (or universal zero page for bss).

Comment: Yes. In principle no difference. But a page frame is 4K, which is a considerable waste if the data section of each so file is loaded separately, and COW. Assuming globals are far less than 4KB, which I am not sure about.